# DotNetBar 10.0.0.3 HScroll not working

Tags: winforms, dotnetbar

I downloaded DotNetBar version 10.0.0.3 and tried to use its ItemPanel control. When I added buttonItems with LayoutOrientation HORIZONTAL, and AutoScroll property to TRUE, it didn't add any Horizontal Scroller to it.

It's working fine when the LayoutOrientation is set VERTICAL and it does add the Vertical scroller in that case.

What's the matter. Am i missing some thing or is this a Bug in this version?

Answer (score 1):

I was banging my head since hours and it was this small cruel property "MULTILINE" which was set false by default. Setting it to true get me what i wanted!